# reopen the question regarding islam a religion of peace?

Tags: discussion

I think we should open this question,

[Is it true that Islam is a religion of peace?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/12699/if-islam-is-the-religion-of-peace-why-did-apostle-mohammed-waged-war-against-ot) and edit this https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/541/how-many-wars-did-prophet-muhamad-pbuh-participate-in to have 1 question only. The title asks 1 question while the body has 2 questions which is against the rules.

I find the closed one a legit question since too many people confuse the world islam with peace.

Hence, I have clicked on the reopen button.

Comment: I see both the question are now open. Good move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm glad to see this kind of activity on meta. Why don't you edit the question to make it higher quality, and then I can re-open it.